# Frozen - Does Elsa unknowingly thaw ice?

Tags: disney, frozen

I've watched the movie a couple of times (young son), and there is a point in 'Let It Go' on Elsa's trek up the mountain where she begins experimenting with her powers.  The moment I am referring to is in the beginning of song, where she is blowing snow back and forth, it cuts to her in the front again with some snow floating just behind her and sweeps her hands behind her and all the snow in the shot and above the frame comes down like water.

Is that snow turned to water, or am I miss-seeing that and it is still frozen?

I thought it pertinent because she consistently refuses to thaw anything because 'she doesn't know how'.  The implications and metaphors here could be discussed, but I'm just wondering what others think and if I am seeing it right.  =)

Comment: When the pieces fall to the ground, you can kind of hear them hitting the snow and it sounds likes little ice balls to me, like hail. I think without her power holding them up, they just fall, not necessarily turn to water.

Comment: A couple of times? Lol. Due to kids, I've now watched this film approximately a million times.

Comment: Oh, that's _definitely_ the sound of water hitting loose snow.  I've heard that hundreds of times in my childhood.

Comment: Yeah, I listened to it closer and it totally sounds like water hitting snow.

Comment: I watched it about six times in a row here and it just looked like a regular old snowfall to me.  I mean it was the wet heavy thick kind but snow all the same.

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty convincing. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Comment: @Valorum I appreciate the points but I don't agree with the result:  the 'no good gesture' still appears to make the snow behind her thaw and fall as water without her seeing it to my eyes.

Comment: @StephenB. - It just sort of drops. There's no evidence of thawing as far as I can see. Note that much the same effect occurs when she's building the bridge. The snow just kinda disappears.

Answer (score 19):

I think you're mis-viewing the scene.

- Elsa uses her powers to make a snow flurry appear in mid-air
- She then uses the "sweep crossed hands" gesture (otherwise known as the "[no good gesture](http://adayinthewife.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/arms-crossed.jpg)") to cancels the power holding the flakes up, which makes the ice crystals **fall out of the air**.

There's no particular evidence to suggest that she's *thawed them* when they drop and when we see behind her (a few seconds later) the snow seems unblemished.

It's also worth noting that in the bridge scene, the snowflakes that she brushes off of the banisters simply disappear in a puff of magic. **It's not clear that any of the snow that we see in the film is actually water-based.**

Comment: Ah, good point on the 'unblemished snow' part.  Although it may be the blurring but it still looks like rain to me =P

Comment: Olaf is water-based (we see him dripping/turning to water when he melts.) However, he may have been created from natural snow already on the ground rather than new snow created by Elsa.

Comment: @AlliterativeAlice - I've actually found a nice quote from "Art of Frozen" about the difference between magical snow and real snow. It doesn't help to answer this question (much) but I will be editing that last sentence shortly.