# Do Elsa and the snow queen never change clothes?

Tags: once-upon-a-time, clothing

In the TV show *Once Upon a Time* - Elsa, mother snow queen and the pirate don't ever seem to change clothes. I can think of several possibilities:

1. They wear the same attire every day.
2. They have magic which takes care of such nitty-gritties.
3. They do change clothes but they have multiple copies of the one set of clothes.
4. They only need to change under-wear.
5. It's silly. You should not be bothered with such trivialities, just watch the silly show. It's magic land.

Which of the possibilities could it be including and besides those above?

Comment: I vote for #5 for anything based on an animated show, and I give you a +1 for including it as an option in your question.

Comment: Uniform clothing is also common in animated work in particular, because the medium doesn't allow as much detail in face and feature to allow you to tell characters apart.  Without the clothes and hair, many animated humans appear much the same.

Comment: Old cat, if you use your comment as the answer, I would upvote you. Yes, that is the answer I'd never thought about - unless someone gives a better reason why animated characters don't ever change clothes.

Comment: There is a funny glimpse of #3 in the Anime show Noir where Chloe, sinister character we don't know much about aside from her unique garb is going to her closet and there are multiple copies of her outfit in there on hangers.

Comment: They DO occasionally change clothes, but if they showed her changing clothes they'd have to move the time-slot.

Comment: See The Simpsons - characters have only changed clothes a handful of times in 25 years on the air, and always gone back to their original clothing by the end of the show :)

Comment: In "olden days" (the loosely defined time period in which fairy tales are thought to occur) people changed clothes much less frequently than they do now. Even two hundred years ago most people would hardly ever have changed clothes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uniform clothing is also common in animated work in particular, because the medium doesn't allow as much detail in face and feature to allow you to tell characters apart. Without the clothes and hair, many animated humans appear much the same.

Comment: I know the OP asked you to post this but how is it relevant to a question about a non-animated series?

Comment: The author **asked** me to place it here. Just being polite.

Comment: This is a valid answer because the non-animated originated from the animated. The non-animated had to identify its characters with those in the animated, especially in the clothing. In fact, this is the best valid answer.

Comment: @BlessedGeek: So the best answer for a question that seems to be asking for an in-universe answer is one that is actually out of universe?

Comment: @BlessedGeek **Emma** - who neither is nor has ever been an animated character - always wears her red leather jacket as well. The out-of-universe reason is of course the one given here by Oldcat: easy to spot for the viewer (regardless if the medium is animation or life-action btw). You should probably have clarified which you're interested in.

Answer (score 3):

The real answer is probably option 5, backed by whichever of options 1-4 you feel fits. However it's likely the choice is not the same for each character.

- Elsa arrives in Storybrook inadvertantly through magic, and apparrently with only the clothes she stands up in. It's likely she keeps wearing the same clothes, possibly with one of the other characters lending her some spare underwear. It's also possible that she wears other clothes while her main outfit is being washed, and we just don't see that. Or her dress may be magic, since [she magically changes clothes at least once in the movie](http://youtu.be/moSFlvxnbgk?t=3m3s). She doesn't need to change clothes for warmth.
- Snow Queen seems to have been in Storybrook a while, so presumably she has managed to acquire multiple outfits, possibly in whatever magical way everyone else in Storybrook acquired their modern clothing, or just the town clothing store. Presumably she has a preferred outfit she wears while 'snow queening', as opposed to running the ice cream shop.
- Hook has his own ship docked in Storybrook, presumably with several changes of clothing in it. We can deduce that he simply prefers the style we always see him in, and has several identical outfits.

Comment: Since I have a daughter that's about 2.5 years old, I've seen Frozen... well, a lot. During the course of the movie, Elsa is originally wearing a green, black and purple dress, but at some point uses her ice magic to completely change her outfit, which she keeps for the rest of the movie. Presumably, she's wearing some sort of fine ice-based outfit. From pictures, the dress in OUAT is similar in style, except that it appears to be fabric. But I see no reason why Elsa couldn't just re-do her outfit with some more ice magic.

Comment: Not having a daughter that age, I bow to your superior knowledge.

Comment: Hook has started wearing modern clothing.

Answer (score 2):

[Frozen - Does Elsa unknowingly thaw ice?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59758/frozen-does-elsa-unknowingly-thaw-ice)

This question(and the entire movie)shows us that Elsa can control Ice and water(up to a point). That being said it would be easier for her to cleanse her clothing slightly in the same way that she was manipulating Ice.

Alternatively though:

It appears that "Once Upon a Time" is not adding to Canon or canon itself, so instead you will have to use common sense and human behavior. If you wish to call her human, of course.

[Is Once Upon a Time adding to Frozen canon?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/70636/is-once-upon-a-time-adding-to-frozen-canon)

1. **They wear the same attire every day.** Well she just came to a strange place and you have to think about how long she has been there. In the "Frozen" movie she recreated her old dress into a new dress with her power. So maybe she cleanses her dress a lot.
2. **They have magic which takes care of such nitty-gritties.** No idea what this means.
3. **They do change clothes but they have multiple copies of the one set of clothes.** There you have to admit they do change clothing. If we go into why people wear matching outfits this could get really goofy.

   - They like the clothing
   - They can't create anything else
4. **They only need to change under-wear.** I think this is a valid point when you see that they can indeed(or at least Elsa) can remake their clothing.

I would say it is a mixture of all the answers. Elsa is busy, with ruling and with being dragged out her land. Maybe she never meddles with fashion anyway. So she has not time to get new clothing. Also, why when she can just remake her dress, and has to just change her underwear.

As for Hook I would say that Hook was accounted for in the previous statements saying he had a ship and that he was caught wearing different attire.